# Hide columns outside of selection in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA to select pay period dates in excel based on a dropdown. How can I hide all columns in a range before and after the selected pay period?

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ppe_start As Long
Dim ppe_end As Long

ppe_start = Range("B1")
ppe_end = Range("B2")

Columns("C:ER").Hidden = True

Range(Columns(ppe_start), Columns(ppe_end)).Select.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Using this code I am receiving a run time error 424: object required.

Comment: if your `ppe_start` is > 2 then your inputs will be hidden also.

Comment: I think i follow what you are saying. I want my inputs to be hidden. I configured the VBA to reference formulas in the sheet. This is likely a crude solution but I really don't know how to run or write a formula in VBA.

Comment: remove the `.Select`

Comment: Thanks Scott. that solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a setup of dates in your drop-down list.

My example data looks like this[image]

Then you will hide all columns except the columns between date (`B1`) 2018-03-01 and (`B2`) 2018-07-01.

I modified your code a bit to be dynamic.

**VBA Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set Sheet name

Dim ppe_start As Date
Dim ppe_end As Date
Dim FoundStart As Long
Dim FoundEnd As Long

ppe_start = Range("B1") 'Set first date
ppe_end = Range("B2") 'Set last date

Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide all columns

With ws
    FoundStart = .Range("3:3").Find(What:=ppe_start, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column - 1 'Find column number where First date exist in row 3
    FoundEnd = .Range("3:3").Find(What:=ppe_end, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column + 1 'Find column number where Last date exist in row 3

    .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(3, FoundStart)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'From Column C until Column First date, hide
    .Range(.Cells(3, FoundEnd), .Cells(3, "ER")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'From Column Last Date until Column ER, hide
    .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 9.71 'To preserv the width of Column B, not necessary
End With
End Sub
```

The result will be this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wizhi. I think this is a bit more than what I require but it looks like it might work.

Comment: Had a little bit of free time ;).